# Does the airy group "commute" with time-compactly supported functions?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am currently reading the book "Introduction to nonlinear dispersive PDEs" by Felipe Linares and Gustavo Ponce and found an equality that really kept my attention. At the top of page 173 (second edition) they are basically trying to compute the following quantity $$
\big\Vert V(t)\big(\theta_\rho(t)J^{-s}v(t,x)\big)\big\Vert_{L^2_tL^2_x},
$$
where $\theta_\rho(t)=\theta(\rho^{-1}t)$, with $\rho\in(0,1)$, where $\theta\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a function satisfying: $$
\mathrm{supp}\,\theta\subseteq[-1,1], \quad 0\leq\theta\leq1 \quad \hbox{and}\quad \theta\equiv 1\ \hbox{ in } \ [-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}].
$$
On the other hand, $J$ is the fourier multiplier: $$
\widehat{J^sf}=(1+\vert \xi\vert^2)^{s/2}\widehat{f}(\xi),
$$
and $V(t)$ denotes the Airy group, given by (recall we are in dimension $1$): $$
V(t)f=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(x\xi+t\xi^3)}\widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi.
$$
Then, as I said before, at the top of page 173 Linares-Ponce wrote $$
\big\Vert V(t)\big(\theta_\rho(t)J^{-s}v(t,x)\big)\big\Vert_{L^2_tL^2_x}=
\big\Vert \theta_\rho(t)V(t)J^{-s}v(t,x)\big\Vert_{L^2_tL^2_x}.
$$
I am really surprised of this equality, a priori I would think that an inequality could be proven but not an equality... So I've tried to prove it, but I haven't succeeded it. So I am wondering if anyone has any hint that could be useful to prove (or disprove) this equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved my own question (and actually it seems that the answer was trivial). The main point is that the operator $V(t)$ is only taking the Fourier transform in space, so if we have a function which only depends on time, we can certainly write $$
V(t)\big(\theta(t)f(x)\big)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(x\xi+t\xi^3)}\mathcal{F}_x\big[\theta(t)f(x)\big](\xi)d\xi=\theta(t)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(x\xi+t\xi^3)}\widehat{f}(\xi)d\xi=\theta(t)V(t)f.
$$
I think this should be correct, at least it matchs the identity Linares-Ponce used.